# Read Throughputs in Summary Report

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, loadrunner

I have hard time to understand the throughput for multiple requests total throughput.

for example, I send 10 request to app server like request 1, request 2, so on, and I get results for them and for total, example, my request 1 has 17/ sec, request 2 has 18/sec and Total throughput is 115/sec. 
so the application throughput is 17/sec or 115/sec ?

I don't know how to explain or understand the results.

Comment: what is *17/ sec* ? you mean Average time?

Comment: 17/sec is Average throughputs for each request. I have sent 10 requests, most of them 17/sec throughputs, I am confused the Total at the bottom of the Summary

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing between response time and [Throughput](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report)

> Throughput is measured in requests per second

Throughput shows how many requests sent in one second

> i.e. 30.0 requests/minute is saved as 0.5.